# NullPointerException in JGitSourceReferencesProvider

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm trying to build [WALA](https://github.com/wala/WALA) project in my Eclipse. However, Maven raises following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) on project com.ibm.wala.util: Error assembling JAR: NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.19.0:package-plugin (default-package-plugin) on project com.ibm.wala.util: Error assembling JAR
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
...
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error assembling JAR
    at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackagePluginMojo.createPluginJar(PackagePluginMojo.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackagePluginMojo.execute(PackagePluginMojo.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.tycho.extras.sourceref.jgit.JGitSourceReferencesProvider.getSourceReferencesHeader(JGitSourceReferencesProvider.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.sourceref.SourceReferenceComputer.addSourceReferenceHeader(SourceReferenceComputer.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackagePluginMojo.updateManifest(PackagePluginMojo.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.packaging.PackagePluginMojo.createPluginJar(PackagePluginMojo.java:214)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the code, it seems that it is not possible to resolve `HEAD` in your repository. I'm not sure how this can happen, but there sems to be something wrong with you Git repository.

Comment: Ran into this as well. I was trying to build before I commited for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar exception and was able to fix it by creating a branch to avoid detached head state and by committing the pom.xml in that branch.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.tycho.extras.buildtimestamp.jgit.JGitBuildTimestampProvider.getTimestamp(JGitBuildTimestampProvider.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.buildversion.BuildQualifierMojo.getBuildTimestamp(BuildQualifierMojo.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.buildversion.BuildQualifierAggregatorMojo.getBuildTimestamp(BuildQualifierAggregatorMojo.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.buildversion.BuildQualifierMojo.calculateQualifiedVersion(BuildQualifierMojo.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.buildversion.BuildQualifierMojo.execute(BuildQualifierMojo.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 20 more
```